# How to associate JSON to a String in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, json

I have a valid JSON shown below

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know how can i associate this with String in  Eclipse IDE

Means i want to do

```
String json = "{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}"
```

but its giving an compilation error , telling String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - string declaration occupying multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886966/java-string-declaration-occupying-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the JSON string was pasted from somewhere, you might want to select the "Escape text when pasting string" option. Then you won't have to escape by hand which can be tideous.

http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.sg/2008/04/cut-and-paste-of-strings-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Really helpful. Didn't know about this feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
String json = "{"
        + "    \"employees\": ["
        + "        {"
        + "            \"firstName\": \"Peter\","
        + "            \"lastName\": \"Jones\""
        + "        }"
        + "    ]}";
```

Answer (score 1):

In `java` you'll need to create the string properly, as

```
 String json = "{"
+" \"employees\": [ "
+"    { "
+"         \"firstName\": \"Peter\","
+"         \"lastName\": \"Jones\""
+"    }"
+"    ]"
+"}";
 System.out.println(json);
```

You'll get

```
 { "employees": [     {          "firstName": "Peter",         "lastName": "Jones"    }    ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following :

```
String json = "{\n"
    + "    \"employees\": [\n"
    + "        {\n"
    + "            \"firstName\": \"Peter\",\n"
    + "            \"lastName\": \"Jones\"\n"
    + "        }\n"
    + "    ]\n}";

System.out.println(json);
```

Output :

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can be configured to enter the escape characters for you.

In Eclipse under the Window menu choose Preferences, in Preferences choose Java -> Editor -> Typing. On the Typing panel there's a checkbox group called "In string literals", select the checkbox labeled "Escape text when pasting into a string literal".

With that box checked, any text you paste into the editor gets escaped so that it is a valid string literal, specifically it will escape the double-quotes.

(This is the same answer as [the accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280935/217324), except I'm actually specifying where the checkbox is within the answer instead of requiring the reader to click on a link to a blog.)